# Django django module not found error no module listings

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\Project_Real\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
 packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\Project_Real\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 42, in check_url_namespaces_unique
   
  File "C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\Project_Real\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
   ......
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'listings.urls'
```

Comment: Share the code, you are using

Comment: Please add the `urls.py` to the question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.